# Would this question be acceptable if I migrated it here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

It has been suggested that [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/web-apps-management-dashboard-what-features-should-be-in-it) might be better answered here.

Would it be OK if I migrated it here (I'm a [moderator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/21/chrisf) on Web Apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is not appropriate for UI because it really seems too localized to his specific business, whatever that may be. Either that, or it isn't a real question, because I have been sitting there staring at it and cannot come up with anything that resembles an accurate answer to his question.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll just close it as "not a real question" or "off topic" where it is. Thanks!